# Proving a general reasult in polynomials.

Tags: analysis, functions, polynomials

If $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) - 1$ where $a, b, c, d$ are distinct integers. Prove that $f(x)$ can't be factorized into integer polynomial with $deg ≥1$

In the above question I proved for three degree polynomial using contradiction. But couldn't use the same for the even degree polynomial.If anyone out there could help me would be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried Gauss’ Lemma? I don’t know if this will work. But , you may try it.

Comment: I am actually a high school student so I have no idea about it. Please I try using some algebraic techniques which a high school student could understand.

Comment: If this had an integer root, then the product of four integers must be 1. So they all must be either 1 or -1, contradicting the distinctness of a,b,c,d

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the expression above could be factorized into 2 quadratic polynomial as well. In that case we cannot say that it will have any integer roots.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan it must be $abcd - 1$? Or I am making a mistake

Comment: Can anyone please look up for the solution.

Comment: Do you mean into any integer polynomial? Or in the same variable $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $~f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) - 1~$ where $~a,~ b,~ c,~ d~$ are distinct integers.

If possible let, $~f(x)~$ can be factorized into integer polynomial with degree $~\ge 1~$ and let $$~f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) - 1=p(x)q(x)~$$ where $~p(x)~$ is a linear polynomial and $~q(x)~$ is cubic polynomial.

Then $$p(a)q(a) = p(b)q(b) = p(c)q(c) =p(d)q(d)=−1.$$ If the coefficients of $~p(x)~$ and $~q(x)~$ must integers they can take only integer values, so in each product one of the factor must be $~1~$ and the other one is $~−1~$. Hence either $~p(x)~$ takes the value $~1~$ twice or it takes the value $~−1~$ twice. But a first degree polynomial
cannot take the same value twice.
Hence a  contradiction arises.

Comment: what about the case of two quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply.  But I think, only one case is enough for contradictory proof. Even after that if you need more, then you can follow the proof of @Pythagoras

Answer (score 2):

By rational root test or [Gauss’s Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) (see the proof there for the lemma over the integers), if $f(x)$ has linear factor over $\mathbb Q$, then $f(x)$ has a factor of the form $x-t,t\in {\mathbb Z}$. But $f(t)=0$ implies $$(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)=1,$$ which is impossible, as $t-a,t-b,t-c,t-d$ are nonzero distinct integers.

If $f(x)$ is reducible but of no linear factor, then by Gauss’s Lemma, $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-1$$ $$=(x^2+Ax+B)(x^2+Cx+D),$$ where $A,B,C,D\in {\mathbb Z}$. It follows that $$f(a)=(a^2+Aa+B)(a^2+Ca+D)=-1$$
$$\Rightarrow a^2+Aa+B=\pm 1.$$ Similarly $$u^2+Au+B=\pm 1,~{\rm for~}u=b,c,d.$$

By the pigeonhole principle (and permuting $a,b,c,d$, $(A,B)$,$(C,D)$ if necessary), one may assume that $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}a^2+Aa+B=1\\ b^2+Ab+B=1\end{array}\right.\Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{c}a^2+Ca+D=-1\\ b^2+Cb+D=-1\end{array}\right.,$$
where $A,B,C,D$ can be solved as $$A=-(a+b),B=1+ab,C=-(a+b),D=-1+ab.$$ It follows that $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-1$$ $$=(x^2-(a+b)x+(1+ab))(x^2-(a+b)x+(-1+ab)). \quad (1)$$ By comparison of coefficient of $x^3$ and the constant term in (1), one has $$a+b=c+d,abcd-1=a^2b^2-1.\quad (2)$$

**Case** 1: $ab\neq 0\Rightarrow a+b=c+d,ab=cd,$ which shows that $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\},$ a contradiction to the condition that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.

**Case** 2: $ab=0$. By symmetry, it suffices to consider the case $a=0$ (so $bcd\neq 0$). Then (2) gives that $b=c+d$, hence from (1), one has $$x(x-(c+d))(x-c)(x-d)-1$$
$$=(x^2-(c+d)x+1)(x^2-(c+d)x-1).\quad (3)$$ By comparison of coefficient of $x$ in (3), one has $$-cd(c+d)=0,$$ which shows that $c+d=0$ (since $cd\neq 0$). This implies that $$0=c+d=a+b=b,$$ contradiction again.

One concludes that if $a,b,c,d$ are distinct integers, then $$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)-1$$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q.$